# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre los distintos tipos de instancias de clase en PHP?

Tags: php

Leyendo el código de una página me he encontrado con lo siguiente:

`ItemForm::plugin_post_item();`

Según la documentación es lo mismo que escribir:

```
$a = new ItemForm();
$a->plugin_post_item();
```

Entonces me surgió la duda, ¿Que diferencia una forma de la otra?, si en teoría hacen lo mismo, ¿No es redundante?. Espero un entendido pueda dar una respuesta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El (::) es un Operador de Resolución de Ámbito el cual puedes acceder a elementos constantes y/o estáticos de una clase, mientras que la forma -> es para acceder a un método no estático o a una propiedad de la Clase

En pocas palabras:

```
:: es para métodos estáticos
-> es para métodos normales
```

Answer (score 2):

`::` Es el operador de resolución de ámbito y se usa para acceder a métodos y propiedades y con ello evitar hacer una instanciacion de la clase a un objeto

```
ItemForm::plugin_post_item();
```

Con lo anterior sólo tendrás acceso a ese método y nada más

Mientras que con

```
$a = new ItemForm();
$a->plugin_post_item();
```

Creas un objeto llamado `a` que a su vez es igual a una instancia de la clase y desde ahí podrás acceder a todos los métodos y propiedades no estáticos que posea la clase

Cabe destacar que por su propia naturaleza, una propiedad que es de tipo `static` y a la cual se accede por medio del operador `::` deberá ser siempre de tipo `public`

La razón...

Las propiedades públicas son accesibles desde cualquier parte del código, sin embargo una propiedad protegida solo es accesible por la propia clase y aquellas que heredan de esa misma clase, por lo cual lo siguiente no va a funcionar

```
class Demo
{
    protected static $name = "alfa";
}


echo Demo::$name;
```

Dando un error de este tipo

> FATAL ERROR Uncaught Error: Cannot access protected property
>   Demo::$name in /home4/phptest/public_html/code.php70(5) : eval()'d
>   code:9 Stack trace: #0 /home4/phptest/public_html/code.php70(5):
>   eval() #1 {main} thrown on line number 9

Entonces la propiedad o incluso un método deberá ser de tipo `public` y quedar así

```
class Demo
{
    public static $name = "alfa";
}


echo Demo::$name;
```